# How to use ground truth images for background subtraction

Tags: python, opencv, testing, image-processing, video-processing

I have downloaded [videos and ground truth data](http://f4k.dieei.unict.it/datasets/bkg_modeling/) from here and I am trying to use it to test out the results of my background subtraction algorithm. I can't for the life of me how they have labelled the ground truth data so which image lines up with which frame of the image/timestamp.

As for how to use I am unsure, but I was thinking of perhaps subtracting the frame from the image somehow. perhaps cv.subtract( in openCV. Then for true positives and negatives and false positives and negatives? Am I on the right track?